# C++ String Stream

Tags: c++, stream

I'm just learning how to use streams in C++ and I have one question.

I thought that each stream has state true or false.  I want to enter each word from the string below and 1 until there is a word, but I get an error:

> cannot convert 'std::istringstream {aka std::__cxx11::basic_istringstream<char>}' to 'bool' in initialization
> bool canReadMore = textIn;

It should be like:

```
antilope  
1  
ant  
1  
antagonist  
1  
antidepressant  
1
```

What am I doing wrong?

```cpp
int main() {
    
    std:: string text = "antilope ant antagonist antidepressant";
    std:: istringstream textIn(text);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ){
        std:: string s;
        textIn >> s;
    
        bool canReadMore = textIn;
        std::cout << s << std:: endl;
        std::cout << canReadMore << std:: endl;
    
    }
    return 0;
    
}
``1
```

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11, [`std::istringstream` operator `bool` is explicit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). What this means is that you must explicitly make the cast yourself:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string        text = "antilope ant antagonist antidepressant";
  std::istringstream textIn(text);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    std::string s;
    textIn >> s;

    bool canReadMore = bool(textIn);
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
    std::cout << canReadMore << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out 
antilope
1
ant
1
antagonist
1
antidepressant
1

0
```

Now, if you use a `std::stringstream` in a bool context, the conversion will be automatic. This is an idiomatic use:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string        text = "antilope ant antagonist antidepressant";
  std::istringstream textIn(text);

  std::string s;
  while (textIn >> s) {
    std::cout << s << "\n";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
antilope
ant
antagonist
antidepressant
```

Comment: More importantly, note how in the original version an empty string is printed before loop exiting. That's because the `fail` flag is set *after* reading the string (`>>`). So it should be checked *after* `>>`, not before.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Note that `bool canReadMore = bool(textIn)` is a function-style cast, and while that will work, old C-style casts (ie `bool canReadMore = (bool)textIn;`) and function-style casts should be avoided when possible. The preferred approach is to use an explicit C++-style `static_cast` instead, eg: `bool canReadMore = static_cast<bool>(textIn);`